# How to flatten nested struct in spark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I am having the following schema in spark and would like to flatten it.

```
root
 |-- binlog_read_timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- row: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- after_values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- before_values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- schema: string (nullable = true)
 |-- table: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

So depends on the value of `type`, I want to do the following thing:

```
IF type == A THEN add new column with after_values.id 
IF type == B THEN add new column with before_values.id 
IF type == C THEN add new column with values.id
```

Any suggestions on how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Any comment for down vote would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("new_column",
   when(col("type") == "A", col("after_values.id")) \
     .when(col("type") == "B", col("before_values.id")) \
     .when(col("type") == "C", col("values.id")))
```